# How to choose the segment sequence start number?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using FFmpeg to split a file into chunks using the segment muxer.

The output is named `output%03d.mp4`, but the first output file is `output000.mp4`

How can I start from 001 instead of 000?

Comment: If this is a programming question you should tag it with [tag:ffmpeg] and the programming language you are using, although note the guidance for that tag says "Questions about interactive use of the command line tool should be asked on Super User or Video Production."  (In that case, I think [Can I set the start number for image sequence output?](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/19511) on [Video Production](https://video.stackexchange.com/) has your answer.)

Comment: @BACON Has nothing to do with programming .

Comment: This is a site for programming questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `-segment_start_number 1` output option.

See the [segment muxer documentation](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-formats.html#segment) for more information and options.

Comment: This one fixed my problem . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use the -start_number option to declare a starting number for the sequence. This is useful if your sequence does not start with img001.jpg but is still in a numerical order. The following example will start with img100.jpg:

```
ffmpeg -f image2 -start_number 100 -i img%d.jpg /tmp/a.mpg
```

For more see at [3.2 How do I encode single pictures into movies?](https://ffmpeg.org/faq.html)

Comment: Maybe my issue was not well expressed . I'm using this ffmpeg line :
`ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -map 0 -segment_time 00:20:00 -f segment output%03d.mp4` from [link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/1670/how-can-i-use-ffmpeg-to-split-mpeg-video-into-10-minute-chunks)

Your command line does not fix my issue :(